# Difference between requestAction and using elements in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, element

Can someone enlighten me further on the difference between calling requestAction directly in the view and using an element? I can see it's been mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455438/cakephp-layout-data-using-requestaction-is-there-another-way). 
Is there real performance concerns with overusing requestAction? I'm using cake 2.0.6

Answer (score 0):

The element is for when the View have code html and php repeated, requestAction is for when integrate a plugin than a big functionality. but you can not abuse the requestAction.

example element:

```
echo $this->element("footer", array('var'=> 1));
// element footer, raisin in the array var
```

example requestAction:

```
echo $this->requestAction('/comments/add/'.$_model.'/'.$_foreignKey, array('return'));
// plugin comments, function add function
```

Comment: Hi del_dan, thanks for the reply but I don't quite understand your answer. Maybe If I elaborate. I have 1 table of articles that I want to display in diff. views depending on a which company authored them. Right now I'm calling a requestAction in the view because making an element for each article list seems laborious.

Comment: In your case it is best to requestAction, because you use a function in controller.

Answer (score 0):

element() loads just an element; that is, a view fragment. It is almost as when you would have copy-pasted that .ctp into the place where you use it. The only difference is that you can tune cache behavior and pass selected view variables as you like.

requestAction() is performing a complete request internally in cake by dispatching a cake request with the given parameters (e.g. URL). Here you can also tune caching, and you can choose to have the rendered view or the contoller's action return value as return value of requestAction().

IMHO this functionality - when used properly - is a very niche feature of CakePHP, as you can create a site in parts. E.g. one action renders the comments, one action renders the post body, one action renders the menu, one action requesting all of these and putting it into a single div, one action requesting that div and putting it into the layout. Each layer can be cached efficiently and such design works great with AJAX where you always like to load just some parts of the page but need all of them upon first page load. You can even have JSON and HTML representation of each.

Comment: Hi sibidiba, thanks for the information. That was my plan to break it all up. I guess I'm trying to have as few ctp files and maximise performance via caching etc. My concern is that when the site hits serious traffic, that one method would've been better to go with than the other.